# iTextSharp not writing all rows from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have a simple class setup to create a PDF from a datatable. I am passing a datatable into the code which has 16 rows but the loop which runs through each datarow stops after row 9 for some reason and I can't tell why. The count is fine throughout but it simple stops.

This is the code:

```
 public class CreatePDF
    {
        static public string GetPDF(DataTable dt)
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            String randomnumber = Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(300));
            string FileName = "PDF" + randomnumber + ".pdf";
            String FilePath = "C:\\TFS\\Portal\\Uploads\\" + FileName;


            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPRow Row = null;
            float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

            //table.SetWidths(widths);

            table.WidthPercentage = 100;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

            cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {

                table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
            }

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                }
            } 
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();


            if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException(
                      string.Format("Final PDF file '{0}' was not found on disk.",
                                     FilePath));
            var fi = new FileInfo(FilePath);
           HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                          String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"",
                                         FileName));
           HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
           HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
           HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName);

         return "a";
        }



    }
```

Comment: When you run it through the debugger, does dt.Rows.Count equal 16?

Comment: Yes it does but I have just figured out the problem, will add it below.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was that it was not setting up the column definition properly. I had to create some additional code to make sure it sets up the correct amount of columns for that table and loops through for each row.

I changed this:

```
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = -1;
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                index++;
                if (index != dt.Rows.Count)
                {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[index].ToString(), font5));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```